# Rendering map coordinates on a Timeline card

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am looking to render a map on a Glass timeline and I already have the location (lat, long) from another service. I tried rendering these coordinates as per the article here: https://developers.google.com/glass/location#rendering_maps_on_timeline_cards but my map does not render.

I tried researching around this, but could not figure out the problem.

Tried this on Glass Playground and used my coordinates, the maps just do not render.

For glass://maps to work, do I need to enable any other API service on my google developer account ? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Mirror API Playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/playground) does not support rendering maps in cards. You need to test this using Glass.

The playground is a tool primarily intended for working on card layouts. It supports many features of the API, but not everything.